# Solving another game theoretical problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

In the wardens
calculation it is assumed that if $A$ were to be pardoned, then with equal probability the warden
would tell $A$ that either $B$ or $C$ would be executed. However, The warden can assign probabilities $\gamma$ and $1-\gamma$ to these events as shown in Table 1.
Thus following events hold:
\begin{align}
A &= \text{"$A$ is pardoned"} \\
B &= \text{"$B$ is pardoned"} \\
C &= \text{"$C$ is pardoned"} \\
W &= \text{"Warden tell $A$ that $B$ will be executed".} \\
\end{align}

I would like to calculate $\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{W})$ as a function of $\gamma$. For what values of $\gamma$ is $\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{W})$ less than, equal to, or greater than $\frac{1}{4}$

I struggle somehow to approach the start.

$$
 \begin{array}{r|cccc}
 & \texttt{Prisoner pardoned} & \texttt{Warden tells A} & \texttt{Probability}\\
 \hline
 & A &  \texttt{B dies}  & \texttt{with probability} \ \gamma \\
 & A &  \texttt{C dies} & \texttt{with probability} \ 1-\gamma\\
 & B &  \texttt{C dies} &   \\
    & C &  \texttt{B dies} &   \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Mamba I made an edit of your table. Please control if it is o.k.

Comment: @ calculus. Thank you!

Comment: It maybe helps, if you explain what $\mathbb W$ is, or more specific what $P(A|\mathbb W)$ means.

Comment: $\mathcal{W}$arden I suppose

Comment: Yes, but this is an event is suppose. Which event is it ? And what is the meaning of $P(A| \mathcal W)$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately,there no other information available as described above.

Comment: I'm still confused about your question. As  stated in the above table the event $\mathcal{W}$ denotes that the warden says B will dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have events:

\begin{align}
A &= \text{"$A$ is pardoned"} \\
B &= \text{"$B$ is pardoned"} \\
C &= \text{"$C$ is pardoned"} \\
W &= \text{"Warden tell $A$ that $B$ will be executed".} \\
\end{align}

By Bayes Theorem we have:

\begin{align}
P(A\mid W) &= \dfrac{P(W\mid A)P(A)}{P(W\mid A)P(A) + P(W\mid B)P(B) + P(W\mid C)P(C)} \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{\gamma\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}}{\gamma\cdot\dfrac{1}{3} + 0\cdot\dfrac{1}{3} + 1\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}} \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma+1}.
\end{align}

Notes:

1. Setting $\gamma=\dfrac{1}{2}$ you get the original example with resulting probability $\dfrac{1}{3}$.
2. Setting $\gamma=0$ we get a resulting probability of $0$. This is because if $W$ occurs it's because $C$ is pardoned and the warden is forced to say $B$ - and if $C$ is pardoned, $A$ cannot be.
3. Setting $\gamma=1$ we get a resulting probability of $\dfrac{1}{2}$. This is because the warden will say $B$ only if $B$ is not pardoned. Effectively, the question has changed from "which of $B$ and $C$ will be executed?" to "will $B$ be executed?", with "B" meaning yes and "C" meaning no. If answered yes, then $A$ and $C$ are equally likely to be pardoned.